# How to fetch localStorage attributes from a webpage in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I would like to fetch a particular key that is stored in the LocalStorage object under the Application tab in the developer's tools.

I use requests to hit the webpage but I have been trying to use python bindings with selenium to fetch the elements. But execute_script on the element fetches as none

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox


browser = Firefox(options=opts)
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
print (browser.execute_script('return localStorage.getItem("se:fkey");'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that your code in principle works, as I get the following results:

```
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
>>> browser = Firefox()
>>> browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
>>> print(browser.execute_script('return localStorage.setItem("bla", "blub");'))
None
>>> print(browser.execute_script('return localStorage.getItem("bla");'))
blub
```

For the example you used I get:

```
>>> from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
>>> browser = Firefox()
>>> browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
>>> print(browser.execute_script('return localStorage.getItem("se:fkey");'))
a65d3ff60687075dfa4fa896a4a1013469e1cabe47542b72924674be03c0c2ee,1583582386
```

However, be aware that the browser that is being started uses a clean browser profile in which (among other things like cookies, bookmarks, history) local storage is clean. Therefore, even if you set some local storage value in your "normal" firefox profile, the firefox browser started by selenium does not have access to "your" local storage.

Probably it's possible to pass a specific browser profile to the `options` parameter when initializing the browser (see https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.options). However, be aware that this makes your code hardly reusable on another machine...